# Where to initialize a rich edit control on another dialog?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC dialog based application that has 2 Dialogs: Main Dialog `CMyDlg`and Second dialog `CMyDlg2`.

On the main Dialog I add a Button "Go dialog 2". So I added a handler for the button so that when clicked it pops up the second dialog. Everything works fine But on the second Dialog I have added a Rich Edit Control from toolbox. I Added for it a variable. I also added a class for the second dialog.

Now If I run the Application I get the dialog one and if I pressed "Go to dialog 2" I got what I want. But I need at some point to change the font of the rich edit control but my program crashes.

So I overrided `OnInitDialog` and inside it do some changes to the control but program crashes. After debugging I found that the handle of rich edit is null?!

So how and where can I change the color or do some initializations to the control?

(I called `AfxInitRichEdit2()` in `OnInitInstance()`)

```
BOOL CMyDlg2::OnInitDialog() {
    m_richEdit.SetWindowText("Hello there!"); // program crashes because the handle m_richEdit is null.

    return TRUE;
}
```

And this is the handler of button that creates the Dialog2 and that contains the rich edit control:

```
void CMyDlg::OnBnClickedButton1(){
    CMyDlg2 theDlg;
    theDlg.DoModal();
// TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

- If I create the rich edit control programmatically then everything works fine because I create it at `OnInitDialog` and then it works fine but I need the one that is I added using the wizard toolbox.

*** The thing is that if I write:

```
    m_richEdit.SetWindowText(""); // program crashes but if I wirte:
    GetDlgItem(IDC_RICHEDIT221).SetWindowText(""); it works fine?
```

Comment: `m_richEdit` won't be `NULL`, but it's window handle will be `NULL` because it's not created as a window yet. You have to call the default method first. Change to: `BOOL CMyDlg2::OnInitDialog(){__super::OnInitDialog();m_richEdit.SetWindowText("Hello there!");return TRUE;}`

Comment: To be precise, the richedit window has already been created in `CMyDlg2::OnInitDialog()`, but it won't be *associated* with the `m_richEdit` variable, unless the base class's `OnInitDialog()` method is called.

Comment: @zett42: How to achieve that?

Comment: Basically like Barmak wrote, but `__super` is Microsoft-specific, I would write `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` instead, which is standard C++.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: thanks finally it works.

Comment: @zett42: Thank you! it works!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: It really works like a charm. But `CMyDlg2::OnInitDialog()` doesn't exist should I add it?

Comment: It looks like you are calling the base class method now `CMyDlg2::OnInitDialog(){CDialog::OnInitDialog(); ...}` that should work.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Should I add `CMyDlg2::OnInitDialog()` because the wizard didn't add it?

Comment: Yes, do add it. Your intention is to make changes during dialog setup, so you need that.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Perfect! I did and it works now. Thank you too much.

Comment: Sure, you are welcome.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: But why this works even if I don't call `CDialog::OnInitDialog()`  I only call: `GetDlgItem(IDC_RICHEDIT22)->SetWindowText("Hello");`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the following code inserted by wizard:

```
void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_RICHEDIT22, m_richEdit);
}
```

This tells the dialog to associate `m_richEdit` with the dialog control `IDC_RICHEDIT22`. But this association is not performed until the base class method `CDialog::OnInitDialog();` is called.

```
BOOL CMyDlg2::OnInitDialog() 
{
    //this line should work:
    GetDlgItem(IDC_RICHEDIT22)->SetWindowText("Hello");

    //this line won't work:
    //m_richEdit.SetWindowText("Hello there!"); <- richedit's handle is NULL

    //this line will subclass m_richEdit
    //plus run other initialization
    CDialog::OnInitDialog(); 

    //m_richEdit is ready
    m_richEdit.SetWindowText("Hello there!"); 
    return TRUE;
}
```

It's recommended to put `CDialog::OnInitDialog()` int the first line, to make sure the initialization is done.

`GetDlgItem` works because the control `IDC_RICHEDIT22` exists in the dialog template and you have a valid dialog handle. You are basically making a simple call based on WinAPI's [`GetDlgItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem):

```
HWND hedit = ::GetDlgItem(m_hWnd, IDC_RICHEDIT22);
::SetWindowText(hedit, "Hello world");
```

There is no additional initialization needed.

But `m_richEdit` is just a C++ object, declared as `CRichEditCtrl m_richEdit;` The constructor for this C++ class doesn't do much besides setting `m_hWnd` to `NULL`.

Once it's associated with a valid window handle, we can begin using its windows methods such as `CRichEdit::SetWindowText`

Comment: Would you mind to explain  why `GetDlgItem(IDC_RICHEDIT22)->SetWindowText("Hello");` works?

Comment: I added more clarification in Edit.

Comment: Understood now! thank you for your help and efforts and time.